# Spark : Create dataframe with default values

Tags: apache-spark, schema, apache-spark-dataset

Can we put a default value in a field of dataframe while creating the dataframe? I am creating a spark dataframe from `List<Object[]> rows` as :

```
List<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> sparkRows = rows.stream().map(RowFactory::create).collect(Collectors.toList());
Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> dataset = session.createDataFrame(sparkRows, schema);
```

While looking for a way, I found that `org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes` contains object of `org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata` class. The documentation does not specify what is the exact purpose of the class :

```
/**
 * Metadata is a wrapper over Map[String, Any] that limits the value type to simple ones: Boolean,
 * Long, Double, String, Metadata, Array[Boolean], Array[Long], Array[Double], Array[String], and
 * Array[Metadata]. JSON is used for serialization.
 *
 * The default constructor is private. User should use either [[MetadataBuilder]] or
 * `Metadata.fromJson()` to create Metadata instances.
 *
 * @param map an immutable map that stores the data
 *
 * @since 1.3.0
 */
```

This class supports a very limited datatypes, and there is no out of the box api for making use of this class for inserting a default value while dataset creation.

Where does one use the metadata, can someone share any real life use case?

I know we can have our own map function to iterate over the `rows.stream().map(RowFactory::create)` and put default values. But is there any way we could do this using spark apis?

**Edit :** I am expecting some way similar to Oracle's `DEFAULT` functionality. We define a default value for each column, according to its datatype, and while creating the dataframe, if there is no value or null, then use this default value.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of an attribute/value you're trying to add as default? (i.e., "I want to add an extra column of Int with a default of zero")

Comment: @JonathanMyers No, I don't want to add another column. I want to read and update the existing value of column. So suppose  List<Object[]> rows contains a record having value -  name,null,1,2019-08-06. Now while creating 'RowFactory::create' can I read some default value instead of null for 2nd column? Casting to the appropriate datatype can be ignored for now. But is it possible in any way?

Comment: This is definitely possible. But again, I need more detail. Does the default value remain constant across every row? How is this default value determined (will it always be 0, for example, or will it sometimes be 1?)

Comment: @JonathanMyers yes, the default value remains constant for a particular column. e.g. for integer column 'A' default = 1,  date column 'B' default = sysdate, string column 'C' default = "defaultValue" etc. Depending upon the datatype of the column, the default value should be set.

Comment: @JonathanMyers I was expecting the StructField should be able to support this functionality. That way we can set a default value for each structField in the dataframe schema, similar to Oracle's DEFAULT functionality. Is there any was possible ?

Comment: @JonathanMyers I found something similar for Scala  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632209/scala-spark-create-object-with-default-value-by-datatype. But, I think (I have no knowledge of scala), they are essentially doing the same thing, iterating over the whole dataframe..

Comment: I have added an answer since this remains consistent across columns. If it doesn't work, we can work together on that solution.

Comment: @JonathanMyers I can not see any answer on this question. Can you please share the link to the answer?